# How to enable an input of definition as optional?

Tags: python, definition, optional-parameters, args, optional-arguments

I have a definition that iterates some functions. However, an argument or in other words input of this function should be optional. For my problem, I am trying to make 'depth' parameter optional. For example, this is a minimax algorithm but sometimes for the experiments, you might not want to apply depth pruning. Therefore, it should be optional.

I have tried the *args method. However, it did not work for me. Also, I made it 'depth = None' but I got an error due to 'depth - 1' value in dynamic programming.

```
def minimax(self, board_state, a, b, *args):
    for x in args:
        depth = x
    turn, board = board_state
    if super().terminal_state(board_state, depth):
        return super().heuristic_value(board_state)
    else:
        if turn == -1:
            value = 250
            for x in super().successor_generator(board_state):
                value = min(value, self.minimax(x, a, b, depth-1))
                b = min(b, value)
                if b <= a:
                    break
        elif turn == 1:
            value = -250
            for x in super().successor_generator(board_state):
                value = max(value, self.minimax(x, a, b, depth-1))
                a = max(a, value)
                if b <= a:
                    break

    result = board_state, value
    return value

object.minimax(state, a, b, depth=None)
```

> ```
> value = min(value, self.minimax(x, a, b, depth-1))
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
> ```

The desired function should work for both way:

```
object.minimax(state, a, b) 
object.minimax(state, a, b, depth=5)
```

Comment: You should use `depth=None` then have an if statement to decide whether or not to prune

Comment: do you mean I should use `elif depth:` instead of `else`

Comment: How are you deciding to end the recursion right now? I don't see a check for `depth == 0`. You need `elif depth` anyways, no?

Comment: you could use `def minimax(self, board_state, a, b, depth=5):` and  it will use `depth=5` when you run `object.minimax(state, a, b)`

Comment: @JohnKugelman `terminal_state` function checks if `depth == 0` and it is optional for `terminal_state`  as `default = None`

Comment: @furas The thing is that, I do not want to use depth parameter sometimes. `depth = 5` works fine but I need to use `depth = None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls

```
object.minimax(state, a, b) 
object.minimax(state, a, b, depth=5)
```

are correct and you should define your method as

```
def minimax(self, board_state, a, b, depth=None)
```

But after you have done that, what you should not do is

```
value = min(value, self.minimax(x, a, b, depth-1))
```

because you know that in some circumstances `depth` will be `None` and so `depth-1` makes no sense in that case. You have to handle the exceptional `None` value explicitly yourself. One way to do that is

```
value = min(value, self.minimax(x, a, b, depth-1 if depth is not None else None))
```